# Error on "update-alternatives" when installing/upgrading nodejs v0.10.30

Tags: node.js, installation, upgrade, ubuntu-14.04

So I get this error when doing apt-get upgrade

```
Setting up nodejs (0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/node is already managed by nodejs
dpkg: error processing package nodejs (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing: nodejs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

NB: "nodejs --version" works, I get a clean "v0.10.30" but "node --version" doesn't since there is no link.

So far, I have tried:

- complete removal of nodejs & new install
- I manually removed the link /usr/bin/node to nodejs after removing nodejs, since it was still there and the issue is related to update-alternatives
- using "update-alternatives --config nodesjs" (something was broken and repaired the first time I used it, but it didn't solve the issue. That error has not reappeared since).

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs`?

Comment: Are you using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) to install node or ?

Comment: @mscdex: yes, I'm using Chris Lea's PPA.

Comment: @Salem: "apt-cache policy nodejs" gives this

nodejs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1
  Version table:
     0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/trusty/main amd64 Packages
     0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Answer (score 10):

Other answers didn't resolved the problem on my setup, maybe because I was using the [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall) repository instead of the official ones.

But I've simply removed all "alternatives" for the nodejs group first:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all nodejs
```

And after that, a `sudo apt-get install nodejs` just worked.

Answer (score 0):

I really encourage you to use nvm to install Node.js on your ubuntu machine (https://github.com/creationix/nvm). With that, the installation of any Node.js version becomes very easy.

Comment: Thank you @jsebfranck! It worked perfectly... when I got nvm working (which took me a while). So now I have my node v0.10.30 working.

However, I guess this is still a "workaround" rather than a "solution", even if nvm seems to be a great tool and I plan to use it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an older version of NodeJS installed and you get a conflict while upgrading.

The only package that uses `/usr/bin/node` is `nodejs-legacy`, so unless you have created that link by yourself or installed NodeJS from sources that's the package you need to remove:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nodejs-legacy nodejs
```

After that just reinstall NodeJS, update and upgrade your software:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

From the output you gave the NodeJS version from the PPA has priority over the other, so you should not have any problem installing it.

Comment: Also the Nodejs version from the default repo installs a lot of packages, so at the end you may want to run  `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks again, @Salem, for your attention. It appears that the "purge" didn't remove anything. However, I then installed and upgraded as you told me to, and it worked without a glitch. Now that you mention it, it's quite possible that I created that link: I'm not sure (it was weeks ago) but it does ring a bell. But the fact is that I removed the link manually after the error occurred and it did not solve the issue... So maybe the installation through nvm solved the problem in some way.

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade nono